# Ajax call is double-posting a form the second time it is submitted

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms

For some reason my ajax call is **double-posting** the second time I submit.

I have a view containing this:

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "BasketPage", new AjaxOptions
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "myDiv",

}))
    {
        <textarea id="comment" name="comment"> </textarea> <br />
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-blue" value="Comment" />
    }
```

The BasketPage Controller Action which is invoked looks like this:

```
public PartialViewResult Create(BasketPage currentPage, string comment)
        {          
                Comment newComment = new Comment()
                {
                    Username = User.Identity.Name,
                    Text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(comment),
                    PageID = currentPage.PageLink.ID
                };

                commentRepository.Save(newComment);

                var model = new BasketListModel(currentPage)
                                {
                                    CommentsList = commentRepository.GetComments(currentPage.PageLink)
                                };

                return PartialView("_Comment", model);
        }
```

**Problem scenario:**

1. I enter a value, submit the form. Everything works as expected.
2. I once again (thus a second time) enter a value, submit the form. NOW the Save method is called twice -  which is resulting in that the value is saved twice in the DB, creating two rows with same value.

If I replace the Ajax.beginform with a regular @Html.BeginForm the Save method is only called once.

What am I missing?

Comment: It's probably that you're including the unobtrusive javascript library into the page twice

Comment: Wow. Nice spotting - even though I didn't even show that I was referencing the .js in the partialView. Thank you @Coulton wished I would have posted this earlier since it's been driving me mad for the last 2,5 hours!

Comment: Great to hear, it's an easy thing to do and a difficult thing to spot :).  I've added it as an answer anyway.  Good luck

Comment: @Coulton great spotting!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's probably that you're including the unobtrusive JavaScript library into the page twice.

Check for and remove any duplicates from either your bundle config or from your included `<script>` tags for it.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue before, I had a partial view with data looking similiar to this

```
<div id="OuterDiv">
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ProcessStuff", "Stuff", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "divWrapper" }, new { @class = "form-horizontal", @id = "frmProcess" }))
            {
            <div ="divWrapper">
            <--add some controls --!>
            </div>
            }
<div/>
```

My controller had code returning the view again:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProcessStuff(WhateverNamespace.Models model)
{
  //do some processing
 return PartialView("_stuff", model);
}
```

The problem was in the view itsself, if you look carefully, my *UpdateTargetId* was inside the ajax form, resulting in the second post returning the partial view and placing the Ajax form inside an already existing Ajax form. This caused all requests from the second one onwards to post multiple times.

The solution here is to change the *UpdateTargetId* to a control that lives outside the ajax form, in this case "OuterDiv"